# $nin with $and in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Filter a user(admin) using mongoose operations.

He need to see all saved files... except which as draft files..

But again he should be able to see his own saved draft file...

#### Code:

```js
filter = {
   '_id':
  $nin://not in (dont show)
  [{
  $and:
  [
  // {_id : _id},//in this id and
  {createBy: {$ne: userId}},//other dan admin and
  {status: {$regex: /draft/, $options: 'm'}} //save as draft
]
}]
}
```

I tried filtering this way but ended with this error..

> exceptionMongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $nin

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find the docs that created by the user or those who are not draft:

```js
files.find({$or: [{createBy: userId}, {status: /^((?!draft).)*$/}]})
```

Comment: That what my code does. The regex is for showing the ones that are not draft.

Comment: I had a mistake in the createBy field name. fixed. try again.